# Get the contents of a line in a string

Tags: vb.net, string, visual-studio-2012, get, find

I am using Visual Studio.net, Visual Basic and I have a question.
If I have a string that has many lines in it, what is the best way to get the contents of a certain line?
E.g If the string is as follows:

```
Public Property TestProperty1 As String
    Get
        Return _Name
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        _Name = value
    End Set
End Property
```

What is the best way to get the contents of line 2 ("Get")?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends on what you mean by "best".

The easiest, but least efficient, is to split the string into lines and get one of them:

```
Dim second As String = text.Split(Environment.NewLine)(1)
```

The most efficient would be to locate the line breaks in the string and get the line using `Substring`, but takes a bit more code:

```
Dim breakLen As Integer = Environment.Newline.Length;
Dim firstBreak As Integer = text.IndexOf(Environment.Newline);
Dim secondBreak As Integer = text.IndexOf(Environment.NewLine, firstBreak + breakLen)
Dim second As String = text.Substring(firstBreak + breakLen, secondBreak - firstBreak - breakLen)
```

To get any line, and not just the second, you need even more code to loop through the lines until you get to the right one.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest is to use [`ElementAtOrdefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb494386.aspx) since you don't need to check if the collection has so many items. It would return `Nothing` then:

```
Dim lines = text.Split({Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.None)
Dim secondLine = lines.ElementAtOrDefault(1) ' returns Nothing when there are less than two lines
```

Note that an index is zero-based, hence i have used `ElementAtOrDefault(1)` to get the second line.

This is the non-linq approach:

```
Dim secondLine = If(lines.Length >= 2, lines(1), Nothing) ' returns Nothing when there are less than two lines
```